# Use of undeclared identifier 'ParseClientConfiguration'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, parse-server

I am having trouble with some code, working in several projects, but for some reason not here.
First of all here the chunk of code I am referring to:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration
                                    configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
                                        configuration.applicationId = applicationId;
                                        configuration.clientKey = @"";
                                        configuration.server = configServer;
                                    }]];
```

This code is related to `Parse-Server`, in a project using `CocoaPods`.

I am getting this error message:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'ParseClientConfiguration'
```

Eventhough I have this line in my code:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

If I go on the code mentioned above and right click on `ParseClientConfiguration` to go to `Jump to Definition`, I see a question mark, meaning the definition cannot be found, as one would expect after seeing the error message.

But if I do the same thing inside another project (working), then I get taken to a file called ParseClientConfiguration.h inside a folder called Pods/Parse, where the definition of ParseClientConfiguration is.

***What could justify this difference?*** As far as I am aware of, I did the same thing for all projects.
The one thing that I can think of is that the project with problems has several targets while the others have only one, but I suppose that should not matter. Any useful hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: which version of parse SDK are you using  ?

Comment: I found the problem. One of the targets (Deployment Target set to iOS 6.0) was preventing CocoaPod from loading the right version of the Parse pod.
All targets using the pod needed to be set at iOS 8.0. So you are right it was an issue with the version of parse SDK.